# Not able to insert milliseconds to sybase DB

Tags: java, sybase

Not able to insert milliseconds to DB.

Am using below code

```
SimpleDateFormat loaderRundate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

In debug mode it's showing milliseconds (20140108 06:57:54.212),but after inserting DB it is showing Jan 8 2014  6:58AM

please suggest me.thanks!

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: Probably the date format in the DB doesn't support milliseconds precision. Try to make it varchar and store the Stringified version of the the Date in it(though I've to tell you that this is not a very good approach).

Comment: Sybase database,have to use "datetime" not varchar.

Comment: according to docs datetime is accurate to 1/300 second. http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks36.htm 
It's possible Sybase doesn't show you fractions of second. Looks like you have to use convert function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code should allow you to insert a date with millisecond accuracy. I have used it with  MySql without any problems.

```
java.util.Date date = getMyDate();
if (date == null) {
    statement.setNull(insertionIndex, Types.TIMESTAMP);
} else {
    statement.setTimestamp(insertionIndex, new Timestamp (date.getTime()));
}
```